# MVC 4 Entity Framework - Foreign Key to UserProfile

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-key-relationship

I've created a standard MVC 4 application using the built in account controllers/models/views. I've now tried to add another controller but I want to create a foreign key relationship to an existing user, but im getting the error message:

The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'CreatedBy' on type 'MVC4App.Models.ListingModel' is not valid. The foreign key name 'UserId' was not found on the dependent type 'MVC4App.Models.ListingModel'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

The Listing Model Code is:

using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

```
namespace MVC4App.Models
{
    public class ListingModel
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }

        public string Instrument { get; set; }

        public string Genres { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; } 

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Or is there a better way I should be doing this?

Also I'm assuming I can just add extra properties to the user profile such as an email address or a link to an avatar image later on in the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the UserId to your entity:

```
namespace MVC4App.Models
{
    public class ListingModel
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }

        public string Instrument { get; set; }

        public string Genres { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int UserId {get; set;}
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; } 

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this worked for question asked, but as far as `Code First` is concerned, this is not possible. as only `Only one identity column per table is allowed`

Comment: I realize this is a bit old, but to answer @komenge-mwandila, there is only one identity column per table.

The Id is that identity column while UserId is just an int.  Granted, its a foreign key which links to an column which may be an identity column, but it is only an int.

This really isn't Entity Framework related as you would see this an time you wanted to have a foreign key between two tables with identity columns, but hopefully this helps clarify the issue.